# How can I implement right click in selenium-webdriver?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

```
var element1 = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="/Projects/_anchor"]'));

               driver.actions({bridge: true})                       
                .click( element1, webdriver.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

I am trying above code but it's not giving me desired output i.e right click on element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var element1 = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="/Projects/_anchor"]'));

driver.actions({bridge: true})                       
    .contextClick( element1, webdriver.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

it's working for me.

Comment: This TypeScript worked for me:

`// @ts-ignore
this.driver.actions({bridge: true}).contextClick(clickableElement, Button.RIGHT).perform();`